# Maintaining Session in Android

Tags: android, session, sharedpreferences

I'm working on an App in which when the user enters the username and password, we get an access token and the expiry time

```
{"Access_token":"abcdef","Expiry":"2012-12-27T05:15:27.4044337Z"}
```

How to redirect the user to the login page when the session expires.

My actual question is how do i detect where the expiry time has arrived or not so that I can redirect to the login page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server should respond with a session expired and redirect. Not up to the client usually.

Else save the expire time (as a shared preference if you want a simple persistent storage for it) and for each request compare current time with this (no need to check this until doing a request).

Comment: true... but unfortunately here i have to tackle the condition... Any ideas ??

Comment: So what happens when it expires and the client ignores it?

Comment: Since I'm already in the next activity (dashboard), now if I send any request the response is not proper...